# I am inserting data with prepared statement it is inserting but when i insert for checking duplicate it gives me error how to solve

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//echo "Did you click me";

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);

$sql  = "SELECT count(1) FROM user_register WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($found);
$stmt->fetch();
if ($found)
{
echo "Email is already exist";
//die;
}
else
{
    echo"Debug";


    $insert_data = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO  user_register (first_name, last_name, mobile,username,user_password) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?,?)");
$insert_data->bind_param("ssiss", $first_name, $last_name, $mobile,$username,$user_password);
print_r($insert_data);
die;
// set parameters and execute
//$fname=ucfirst($_POST['first_name']);
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['first_name']);

$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['last_name']);
$mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['mobile']);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
$user_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['user_password']);

    if($insert_data->execute()){
        echo "Inserted";
    }
    else{
        echo"Error";
    }
    $insert_data->close();
        $conn->close();

}


}
```

I want check email duplicacy in my code with prepared statement and if not available insert otherwise show error
but when i check email it is working but it is not inserting new user with new email please help me.

> ERROR:Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\wamp64\www\vaibhav\prepared-statement with session\insert_data.php on line 277

Comment: show your code not an image

Comment: Is one of your colums a boolean?

Comment: At least `password` is a reserved word, and can not be used unquoted as a column name.

Comment: any column is not boolean but i am  Generating random password here

Comment: Just make your email column as a unique key in your database.

Comment: but id is already a unique key there i have changes to unique but not working

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: @04FS `password` is a *key* word, not reserved. It should be backticked (not quoted - quotes are for values) as a column name.

Comment: There is no need to escape strings in a prepared statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//echo "Did you click me";

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);

$sql  = "SELECT count(1) FROM user_register WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username_stmt);
$username_stmt = $username;
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($found);
$stmt->fetch();
 if ($found)
 {
   echo "Email is already exist";
   //die;
 }
else
{
   echo"Debug";
}
```

you missed one line of code. Hope this works

Comment: I have add if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ this line

Comment: @Vaibhav what do you mean?

Comment: I have included isset button here i mean that .

Comment: you missed one line of code. Hope this works ?? it means that i am missing isset button ? Am i right ?

Comment: @Vaibhav change `$stmt->bind_param("s", $username_stmt);` and add
`$username_stmt = $username;` this

Comment: @Vaibhav with my code? Don't forget to vote up and to accept my answer :)